# Use Mobile Browser UI for menu

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

On my travels I found this website http://pawtrack.com/, which uses an interesting mobile menu. 
As someone always on the lookout for a solution for a mobile menu, I was intrigued on how the menu for this site worked. When the burger nav is pressed on my android phone, this expands a menu which seems to have been generated by the browser.

[This image shows how the menu appears on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtX4J.png)

I have inspected the source on desktop and mobile but I can't understand how this is achieved. Is this some kind of plugin or script? I'm sure the answer is quite simple but I can't discern it myself.

Any help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they used two menu :
one for large devices and second for small devices.
They used select dropdown for mobile devices so it looks like dropdown menu...

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Figured it was something simple. Thanks.